# How do I make the command java -version work on my computer with Windows 8.1?

Tags: java

**Problem**
I've installed Java 9 on my computer with Windows 8.1, followed instructions on the Internet to configure system variables and the commands `java -version` and `javac -version` worked on Command Prompt.

Then I had to change to Java 10, so I installed, changed the system variables, but now only `javac -version` works, when I try to use `java -version` I get errors.

```
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

I need Java working so I can follow some online classes, I don't want to get stuck because there is something wrong with my installation.

**Information about my Java installation**
I've used the jdk-10.0.2_windows-x64_bin.exe installer I've got from Oracle's website.
I've got the folders jdk-10.0.2 and jre-10.0.2 on C:\Program Files\Java after running the installer.

**My system variables configurations**
My user's PATH variable:
C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts;C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37;C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

My JAVA_HOME system variable:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2

My Path system variable:
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;

Comment: Which Java JDK did you download and how did you install it? Did you run the installer from oracle or did you download an open jdk distro and just unzip it somewhere?

Comment: **I** always remove the `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` from PATH (or move it to the end, after the JAVA_HOME one (which I also have in system PATH)) - mostly it contains a link to wrong java (I believe not always updated when new version is installed)

Comment: @Deadron, I've downloaded an installer from Oracle's website, I runned it and the installer created the folders jdk-10.0.2 and jre-10.0.2 on C:\Program Files\Java.

Comment: @user15358848, I removed C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath; from Path system variable, opened a Command Prompt and the comand java -version is working now, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alluded to by @user15358848 the oracle installer does this weird thing where it creates a link to the jdk in addition to messing with the path. You can see it added to your path C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath; It most likely it broken after the installation steps you have taken up to this point. If you want to use the JAVA_HOME variable then remove the oracle entry and add %JAVA_HOME% to your path.  You will need to restart the console and or application to pick up the new path variable.

Comment: better add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` as is already being done (users PATH variable) - advantage no need to change PATH later on, just JAVA_HOME (I use to switch versions)